# What is difference between planar, semi planar and interleaved format.?

Tags: colors

Difference between color models and color space

how RGB565 is different from RGB888 any suggested link

YUV vs RGB vs YCbCr.?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

RGB is an additive color model where red, green, and blue intensities are added together in different combinations to produce a exhaustive set of colors.

RGB888 --> R is an 8 bit value varies from 0 to 255. Same for G and B.
RGB565 --> Here R is of 5 most significant bits from R (8 bits) of RGB888.
           Here G is of 6 most significant bits from G (8 bits) of RGB888.
           Here B is of 5 most significant bits from B (8 bits) of RGB888.

If you see the mathematical calculations of converting from RGB888 to RGB565, it looks as below:

> short int rgb565_pixel; rgb565_pixel = ((R >> 3) << 11) | ((G >> 2) << 5) | (B >> 3);

It is the conversion of 24 bits per pixel to 16 bits per pixel.

Coming to YUV: YUV is the color format where you can have a complete separation of brightness and color components from RGB format.

Y represents Brightness components where as Cb and Cr represents Color components.

Planar: In memory, Y followed by Cb and followed by Cr

> [Y1Y2......][Cb1Cb2......][Cr1Cr2.......]

Semi Planar: In memory, Y followed by interleaved data of Cb and Cr, looks as below:

> [Y1Y2......][Cb1Cr1Cb2Cr2......]

Interleaved: In case of YUV422 interleaved data, it looks as below:

> Y1U1Y2V1   Y3U2Y4V2 ... ...

Answer (score 1):

There are various color space system.

- RGB  (Mostly used by Capture or Display devices)
- YUV  (YPbPr in analog system) (YCbCr in digital system) (Mostly all Video/Image processing/compression happen in this format. As Luma and chroma component are separate)
- HSB hue satuaration brightness. (Alternative representations of the RGB color)
- CMYK (Print media uses this color space)

---

Various YUV formats (8 bits only)

**1. Planner**

- All Y would be in one array/plane, then all U would be in another array/plane and then V would be in another array/plane
- Here all 3 array can be at different offset in single buffer also.

I420, I422

reversed planners or interleaved planners :

YV12 is exactly like I420, but the order of the U and V planes is reversed

**2. Semi Planner**

- Semi planar formats have two planes instead of three, one plane for luminance, and one plane for both chrominance components.
- Here both array can be at different offset in single buffer also.

NV12, NV16

reveresed semi planners or interleaved planners :

Here order of U and V get interchanged in 2nd plane.

NV21, NV61

**3. Packed formats**

In packed formats, you usually have only one plane. (This is something like RGB)

( packet formats cannot normally deal with vertical sub-sampling.)

UYVY or Y422

YUY2 or V422 (reversed format)

---

A lot of confusion get created because all different subsystem has their own format/fourCC/macro to identify any format.

like Gtreamer/ffmpeg/v4l2 etc.