# Name for the opposite of 'interleaved' data layout

Tags: terminology, memory-layout, data-oriented-design

In computer graphics as well as in data-oriented design, there is the term 'interleaved', referring to a specific way to lay out data in memory. So for some data with attributes `a`, `b` and `c`, the memory layout `a_1, b_1, c_1, a_2, b_2, c_2, ...` would be called 'interleaved'. The opposite layout would be `a_1, a_2, ..., a_n, b_1, b_2, ..., b_n, c_1, c_2, ..., c_n`.

Is there a single word that describes this other layout that could be used to name a type? So `InterleavedBuffer` vs. `???Buffer`.

I know the terms 'Struct-of-Arrays' (SoA) and 'Array-of-Structs' (AoS), but neither one is a single word and I don't want to use abbreviations, especially ones that are so similar.

Comment: Unravel, unweave, de-interleave, uninterlace, uninterleave, though in your case it's more "Transpose"-ing a data layout.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of image formats and the storage of color channel data, the opposite of interleaved would be *planar*.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26459276/1084865.